# Force verbose error report

Tags: erlang, elixir

Once running my test I faced this:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 29-Jul-2016::01:34:22 ===
** Generic server <0.141.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {send_req,
                           {{url,
                                ***************,
                               *****************,443,
                                undefined,undefined,"/api",https,hostname},
                            [{"X-API-Version","0.5"},
                             {"Accept","*/*"}],
                            post,<<>>,
                            [{is_ssl,true},
                             {ssl_option,
                                 [{certfile,
                                      <<"/Users/slava/src/api/cert_dev.pem">>},
                                  {password,"nil"}]}],
                            15000}}

** Reason for termination == 
** {{badmatch,false},
    [{ibrowse_lib,get_value,2,
                  [{file,"/Users/slava/Documents/src/api/deps/ibrowse/src/ibrowse_lib.erl"},
                   {line,184}]},
     {ibrowse_http_client,check_ssl_options,2,
     {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},
     {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}
```

Then I ran the same test and it failed with small error message. Very uninformative.

Can't figure out what actually forced this verbose report.

Usual one:

```
1) test get vehicle data by vin 
     test/adapter_test.exs:14
     match (=) failed
     code: %HTTPotion.Response{} = Adapter.request(:get, 'vehicles', vin: @vin)
     rhs:  %HTTPotion.ErrorResponse{message: "closed"}
     stacktrace:
       test/remoto_adapter_test.exs:15: (test)
```

Comment: Can you also post the "small error message" from the later test run?

Comment: Looks like the first attempt crashes due to some ssl option problem. The second crash could be that the server isn't running anymore. Maybe the server crashed after the first request failed?